# Clarification Changing of Bases

Tags: linear-algebra

I just need some clarification if what I am doing is correct.

Let $T$:${M_{2x2}}\to{P_{3}}$(R)be the linear transformation defined by

$T\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}$=$(a - b) + (a - d)x + (b - c){x^{2}} + (c - d){x^{3}}$

Consider the bases $∝=${$\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\1&0\end{bmatrix}$,$\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$, $\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$,$\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\1&1\end{bmatrix}$} of ${M_{2x2}}$(R), and $β=${$x, x - {x^{2}}, x - {x^{3}}, x - 1$} of ${P_{3}}$(R)

Find $[ T ]_α^β$ , which is equal to $[T(α)]_β$, but I will just use the first Transformation to see if what I am doing is correct.

$[T]$($\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\1&0\end{bmatrix}$) = $(1 - 0) + (1 - 0)x + (0 - 1){x^{2}} + (1 - 0){x^{3}}$ = $1 + x +-{x^{2}} +{x^{3}}$, we have to write this in terms of the basis β, thus, {${c_{1}}(x) +{c_{2}}(x - {x^{2}}) + {c_{3}}(x - {x^{3}}) + {c_{4}}(x - 1)$} = $({-c_{4}})1$ + $({c_{1}}+{c_{2}}+{c_{3}}+{c_{4}})x$ + $({c_{2}}){-x^{2}}$ + $({-c_{3}}){x^{3}}$ , s.t. ${c_{4}}=-1$, ${c_{2}}=1$ + ${c_{3}}=-1$ and ${c_{1}}=2$ because ${c_{1}}+{c_{2}}+{c_{3}}+{c_{4}}=1$, ${c_{1}}=1$ - ${c_{2}}$ - ${c_{3}}$ - ${c_{4}}$ = 2.

So would I be correct in saying that the first vector of the matrix

$[ T ]_α^β$=\begin{bmatrix}2\\1\\-1\\-1\end{bmatrix}